# HTML table with row headings

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do you style a table with columns of data instead of rows? (or how do you build a table where the column headings relate to the row headings?)

Comment: I think this needs context. And some of your code. And a description of what, precisely, you want to achieve? Also, if you could explain what you've already tried, and what went wrong (or just didn't work) that'd help. You might also benefit from taking a read of [how to ask a great question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want to know how to style columns in a table. What you need is the [col tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp).

Here's an example:

```
<table>
    <col/>
    <col style="background-color: #ffff00"/>
    <col/>
    <thead>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can use divs](http://www.ehow.com/how_4844373_columns-using-div-tags.html). And then, in each column, you could use more divs one for each row.